# Windows Server 2012 R2 System Time cannot be changed

Tags: window, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 on Azure.

The System Time in "Date and Time" cannot be set to an ealier date, but can be set to a future date.

NOTE:

1. Whenever I set to an ealier date, the system time got changed to the current correct time automatically.
2. The Internet Time sync has been disabled already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Disable Windows Time service ,a and set it to Manual
   [image]
2. Disable Hyper-v Time Sync service , and set it to Manual
   [image]
3. Make sure  “Sync with Internet time ” option is unchecked.
   [image]
4. After finishing the above 3 steps, you can change the system time and monitor

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps
fixing time error on serve 2012 setting time either backwards or forward by hours.

Open MSServer 2012

> Windows + run to open

> Type in Regedit

Or
if open with admin rigths open the Apps > search tab, then click type in regedit, open as admin.

If prompted by the UAC click yes

> Go to HKEY_LOCAL MACHINE\SYSTEM\CURRENT CONTROL SET\CONTROL\TIMEZONE INFORMATION.

> Go to Active time bias - set value to 0

> Go to bias set value to 0

> Time zone key type/modif value to area

Make sure the daylight name responds to area e.g @tzres ; -411 ;
Standard name is @tres.dll; -412

> Close/restart server

> opne cmd with admin rigths

> run w32tm/tz utility to verify time bias. & date name

> To disable daylight go to disable auto daylight

to disable auto daylight, open set value to 1.

Use nettime utility as below to align all domain computers to to the server as below.

> open cmd with admin rights then type in the below

nettime/set/y